# WordPress - Google Fonts not working in .php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

I the use 'Flexible Invoices for WooCommerce PRO' plugin and I have a problem. Based on the .php file, a .pdf file is generated.
I add a link to the Poppins font to the .php file, but after opening the file on the web page, the fonts do not work. Ultimately, it is supposed to be a pdf file.
I tried different points:

1. I added to the  section and to the  container

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100;300;400;500;600;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
body, p, tr, th, td {font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif!important;}
```

2. I used the @import option:

```
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100;300;400;500;600;700;900&display=swap';
```

3. I used a separate .css file with @media print {}
4. I added a function to the functions.php file

```
function wpb_add_google_fonts() {
   wp_enqueue_style( 'wpb-google-fonts', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100;300;400;500;600;700;900&display=swap', false );
   }
   
   add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_add_google_fonts' );
```

Unfortunately, the Poppins font still does not work. Do you have any ideas on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Everything is working on my end. Poppins renders correctly. Here is what I tested it with.

```
<?php

/**
 * Enqueue Poppins font from Google Fonts.
 *
 * @link https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Poppins?query=Poppins#about
 */
wp_enqueue_style( 'google_fonts', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300&display=swap', array(), wp_get_theme()->version, 'all' );

add_action( 'style_loader_tag', 'style_loader_tag_google_fonts', 10, 3 );
if ( ! function_exists( 'style_loader_tag_google_fonts' ) ) {
    function style_loader_tag_google_fonts( $tag, $handle, $src ) {
        if ( 'google_fonts' === $handle ) {
            $tag = str_replace(
                "<link rel='stylesheet'", 
                "<link rel='preconnect' href='" . esc_url( 'https://fonts.gstatic.com' ) . "' /><link rel='stylesheet'", 
                $tag
            );
        };
        return $tag;
    };
};
```

You can also specify `media="print"` straight from the tag.

```
//... array(), wp_get_theme()->version, 'print' );
```

Comment: I used the code above but it still doesn't work. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap or other Framework ?

Comment: No, it is a .php file which the code generate to a .pdf file. I use this plugin: https://flexibleinvoices.com/products/flexible-invoices-woocommerce/